# Is it Possible to use PHP HttpRequest in WAMP?

Tags: php, wamp, httprequest

I am trying to use PHP HttpRequest Class and it seems that it's not installed with WAMP.
Is it possible to have this extension available on Windows. I saw somewhere that "a DLL for this PECLis not available at this moment".

Can someone confirm if it's possible to use PHP HttpRequest on Windows

Comment: WAMP as in "Windows,Apache, MySQL and PHP" or as in "www.wampserver.com"?

Comment: WAMP as "Windows,Apache, MySQL and PHP".

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In case you mean the class described at http://docs.php.net/class.httprequest: It's exposed by the  [http extension module](http://docs.php.net/manual/en/book.http.php).
There are some win32 builds of this module (for php 5.3) at http://downloads.php.net/pierre/.

Comment: I downloaded the module: "php_http-5.3-nts-svn20091125-vc6-x86.zip" and copied the "php_http.dll" file in the folder "C:\wamp\bin\php\php5.3.0\ext". I have added the required line("extension=php_http.dll") in php.ini. Yet I get the message, "module could not be found".
Why would this occur.

Comment: **a)** What does `<?php phpinfo();` say about your `PHP Version`, the `Compiler`, `Debug Build` and `Thread Safety`? **b)** Try to start the apache as a console application (instead of a service). Are there any error message in that console?

Comment: Version: 5.3.0
Compiler: MSVC6 (Visual C++ 6.0)
Debug Build: no
Thread Safety: enabled.

Comment: By trying to install apace from console: I got the error message php5.dll was not found.

Comment: `Thread Safety: enabled` - You've downloaded the nts (non-thread-safe) version of the dll.

Answer (score 2):

Try this version - php_http-5.3-svn20091125-vc6-x86.zip - it worked for me. Previous to this I try other versions - but they all end in error.

Comment: VC9 counterpart that worked for me (Acquia-Dump, PHP 5.3): php_http-5.3-svn20091125-vc9-x86.zip --- available at http://downloads.php.net/pierre/