# Problem loading dynamic library in WAMP

Tags: php, wampserver

I have downloaded a dynamic library from the location: http://downloads.php.net/pierre/.

The specific file I downloaded is: php_http-5.3-nts-svn20091125-vc6-x86.zip.

I have copied the file (php_http.dll) into the folder: C:\wamp\bin\php\php5.3.0\ext.

In php.ini, I added the line: extension=php_http.dll.

But I am getting the warning consisting of message: "PHP Startup: Unable to load dynamic library".

Do I need to do anything else to have this module enabled?

Comment: Strongly related to (if not a duplicate of) http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3634969/is-it-possible-to-use-php-httprequest-in-wamp

Comment: Yes, I realize they are addressing the same issue. Actually, in this thread I would like to know why would such loading error would occur, using my current problem as an example.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Maybe it's for a version other than your PHP's?

Comment: My current version is 5.3 and I believe this extension is also for the same version.

Comment: PHP in Wampserver is a thread safe version (you can check it in phpinfo), so you need this file: http://downloads.php.net/pierre/php_http-5.3-svn20091125-vc6-x86.zip
Not sure if that will solve the issue though.

Comment: But I'm still having problem with loading php_http extension!
I'm using wamp

Comment: @Alireza maybe your problem is different, if you are still having it, start a new question explaining your problem.

Answer (score 0):

There are several "attributes" that must be in agreement in both the php core and the extension module. You can find all those values for the php core in the output of [phpinfo()](http://docs.php.net/phpinfo)

- the API version (e.g. 20090626 for the current 5.3.3 version)
- is it a thread-safe (ts)  or a non-thread-safe (nts) build *<- this one's apparently your problem.*
- is it a debug build
- did the compiler used to build a) the core and b) the module produce compatible code?

An extension module dll can also have additional dependencies that may or may not be fulfilled, e.g. another .dll is referenced but not present. Amongst other tools you can use [ProcMon](http://technet.microsoft.com/de-de/sysinternals/bb896645.aspx) to monitor which .dlls are looked for and which are un-/successfully loaded.

Answer (score 0):

For anyone that has tried the above "answers" without success, do this. Get the official Windows files from here. Make sure to (1) use the right version for your php and (2) use the right threading. Use NTS (not thread safe) if you are using fact cgi, and use thread safe if you have loaded php as an apache module.

http://windows.php.net/downloads/pecl/releases/http/

To verify it worked, look at the phpinfo() output and ensure there is a http section.