# {WAMP SERVER} Fatal error: Class 'HttpRequest' not found in C:\wamp\www\project_name\file.php

Tags: php, wampserver

I am using Wampserver 2.5 on windows 10 for my PHP project and my PHP version is 5.5.12
I am trying to use SMS sending API, code is:

```
<?php

    $request = new HttpRequest();
    $request->setUrl('http://api.jaldise.net/restapi/sms/1/text/single');
    $request->setMethod(HTTP_METH_POST);

    $request->setHeaders(array(
    'accept' => 'application/json',
    'content-type' => 'application/json',
    'authorization' => 'Basic QWxhZGRpbjpvcGVuIHNlc2FtZQ=='
    ));

    $request->setBody('{  
    "from":"JaldiSe",
    "to":[  
    "923420563069",
    "41793026834"
    ],
    "text":"Test SMS."
  }');

  try {
  $response = $request->send();

  echo $response->getBody();
} catch (HttpException $ex) {
echo $ex;
}
```

when I run this file in browser the following error shows up this error message:
[image]

I added the http.dll file and extension in php.ini but to no avail.

Comment: like this? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3634969/is-it-possible-to-use-php-httprequest-in-wamp

Comment: I told u my php version in 5.5

Comment: and the post u comment is about php 5.3 and yes i already tried this fix

Comment: it didnot work atall

Comment: So your password really is "Aladdin:open sesame" ?

Answer (score 0):

There used to be a `pierre` folder that had this dll compiled for windows, but that appears to have disappeared recently.

However if you [look here](http://windows.php.net/downloads/pecl/releases/) you will find all sorts of PHP extensions available for various PHP releases and various compilers.

`php_http` can be found [here specifically](http://windows.php.net/downloads/pecl/releases/http/2.5.5/logs/)

Remember that for WAMPServer you need the Thread Safe(TS) Version

Comment: well let me try i will let u know the results